# Expand all jquery-UI accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I was trying to build a jQuery-UI Accordion. Does someone know how I can make a button in order to make all expand.

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" )
      .accordion({
        header: "> div > h3"
      })
      .sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
          ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
          $( this ).accordion( "refresh" );
        }
      });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g0ogLhey/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the widget structure, you can see that `.ui-accordion-content` of each `.ui-accordion-header` classes has a simple css directive: `display:none;`.

Manipulating that directive in conjuntion with some other stuffs, accordions can be expanded or hidden all with one click.

Here's your fiddle updated with some lines of code to do what you want -> https://jsfiddle.net/g0ogLhey/1/

Excuse me for the not well organized code. It's late and surely with a bit of time available, it may be better written.

Consider my code as a starting point for improving yours.

Comment: Can you take a look at this one also, I appreciate it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703271/draggable-jquery-ui-accordion-header

Comment: @Masih the question you linked has been removed. Did you solved it?

Comment: I did not solve it, I wanted to change a lot of things in the question so I thought I make a new one. Sorry about that. This is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724895/jqueryui-accordion-is-not-sortable-anymore